# The evil CORS/CORB - Spring and hibernate, Springboot, Maven and Angular js 2, not working - Allow access control origin

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, cors, maven-2

Please assist, I have tried all sorts of ways, to fix this bug, I have tried Tomcat `web.xml` by adding a filter mapping, `CorsFilter` bean, `@CrossOrigin`, as well as disabling browser web security, but still, this bug is not going ... perhaps it is hidden behind something that I am unable to sport. Is there anyone with better understanding why this bug is not going away.

below is my `ProductApplication.java` bean method:

```
 @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguarationSource(){

        CorsConfiguration configurations = new CorsConfiguration();

        configurations.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configurations.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configurations.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Allow-Control-Allow-Headers","Allow-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Request-Method","Allow-Control-Request-Headers","Origin","Cache-Origin","Content-Type", "Authorization"));
        configurations.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("DELETE","GET","POST","PATCH","PUT"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configurations);
        return  source;
    }
```

I've also tried using a bean  :

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter(){

UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

config.setAllowCredentials(true);
config.addAllowedOrigin("*");             
config.addAllowedHeader("*");
config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");

source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);                      
FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
bean.setOrder(0);

return source;
```

I've also tried using a seperate class annotated with `@Configuration`:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfig{

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter processCorsFilter(){

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");             
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);                      
    //FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    //bean.setOrder(0);

    return new CorsFilter(source);

    }
```

I have also tried the `@CrossOrigin` annotation in controller class:

```
 @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:3000") 
    @GetMapping("/client")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Client>> getAllClients() {

        List<Client> clientList = services.getClientsList();
        if(clientList != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(clientList, HttpStatus.OK);
        }else{
            return  new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note : I am aware that this could possible be a duplicate question, however, i've tried all the methods mentioned in previous questions ... and I cant win... surprisingly even disabling browser web security doesnt win agaisnt this evil bug... please help, you help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are any of them being invoked? If you check in the browsers developer tools, are any of the headers being returned?

Comment: Yes I get 404 not found error : with message no access control origin

Comment: Well if you got a 404 error, that would imply your URL is incorrect, can you test the URL in postman?

Comment: Let me do that but : the URL is as simple as http://localhost:8080/client

Answer (score 1):

According to the [(Spring) CORS documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html):

> The easiest way to ensure that CORS is handled first is to use the
>   `CorsFilter`. Users can integrate the `CorsFilter` with Spring
>   Security by providing a `CorsConfigurationSource` using the following:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
            .cors().and()
            // ... more configuration calls here
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

I've used this myself by overriding the [configure](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/47d9669dbf87ae00b1bff85d99c572834b2d6c2b/server/src/main/java/com/gms/config/security/SecurityConfig.java#L67) method ([WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#configure-org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity-)) as described previously and by providing a [CorsConfigurationSource](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/47d9669dbf87ae00b1bff85d99c572834b2d6c2b/server/src/main/java/com/gms/config/security/SecurityConfig.java#L94) bean and it works.

---

Related readings:

- [HttpSecurity#cors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#cors--)

Comment: I saw this post also... but I got Confused by the elipes the three dots ... what is supposed to be in place for those 3 dots in line 9?

Comment: Those three dots indicate that more configuration can be added. See [this example](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/47d9669dbf87ae00b1bff85d99c572834b2d6c2b/server/src/main/java/com/gms/config/security/SecurityConfig.java#L68). This is a demo project of mine where more configurations are added.

Comment: @NeoSono I edited the code in order to make that clear

Comment: do I also need to override configure method...?  Or just go ahead with the bean only ?

Comment: @NeoSono, yes when you use Spring Security, See [HttpSecurity#cors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#cors--) I'll add it to the post

Comment: Thing is I dont use jwt... I just hash the password and send json object to server for validation...besides am not much of a senior ...am still paving my way to intermediate level in java...Please be patient with me.@lealcedeiro

Comment: @NeoSono, no problem. I struggled with this as well the first time I did it. BTW: the linked [GitHub project](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms) is also implemented with [jJWT](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) and Angular (+ many other thechnologies)

Comment: Perhaps I can override the method and put nothing a inside ? Is it okay like that. Since its a void return type

Comment: @NeoSono You can try that, yes. Indeed it won't give you any error. Did you try with `http.cors()` only and providing a bean of type `CorsConfigurationSource`? Didn't it work? Make sure the bean has the proper configuration... i.e.: [this](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/47d9669dbf87ae00b1bff85d99c572834b2d6c2b/server/src/main/java/com/gms/config/security/SecurityConfig.java#L96) permits requests from any origin

Comment: You are deep ... where/ in which method is http.cors() supposed to be planted...? Configure? Oh okay ... meaning I can just break the cors() and omit and ....

Comment: @NeoSono, yes, inside `configure`, as I posted in the answer.

Comment: Still ... same error ... I added  the http.cors.(); access not allowed...

Comment: @NeoSono There must be something else interfering with this. Do you have a GitHub repo in which I can take a look at ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was attending a 2 hours prayer service. I have bit bucket. I also have git hub but I haven't been active on git ... I am active on bit bucket. And please may I push this repo tomorrow in the afternoon... In South Africa we have data problems...We buy data ... and now am out of data... but tomorrow as soon as I come back from the meeting at 11:00am- 16:00pm I will push the repo. Thank you for your help. God bless you.

Comment: @lealcedeiro is think I am misunderstanding something here, In my application properties I set the port to 8009: however my tomcat runs on 8080, now 8080 = 404 and 8009= 401 on postman and on chrome browser 8009: gives me 302... and I no longer understand, which port must I use in my angular call 8080 or 8009?  Although they all return cors error...

Comment: It should be the one in `8009`. Now this `401` means you're accessing a protected resource. Remember by default Spring Boot (if the [security-starter](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/47d9669dbf87ae00b1bff85d99c572834b2d6c2b/server/build.gradle#L72) was added) has the security mechanism active active if you don't set it otherwise with something like `security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false`.

Comment: And yes i have added the security dependency for future purposes ... and now do I add that lime in my applications properties?

Comment: No need to build when am making changes to application properties right? I just wanna run, right ?

Comment: If I'm running the app and I change something in the `application.properties` generally I rebuild/re-run the project (I suppose it depends on the IDE/tool-set you're using)

Comment: I get the same 401... perhaps I should remove the security dependancy since I am not gonna be using security.

Comment: I got 200! After removing the security dependancy... surely angular will also return 200 ☺thanks for your time @lealcedeiro

Comment: @user184994 i need your help man... ive pushed my springboot project on bitbucket, can you give me your email so that I can give you permission to my bit bucket repo ...? Íve also pushed the angular front end repo as well ... : At some point i hve to know how to deal with this error(the evil 401 error ). I believe it is better for me to try and figure it out when I can, as soon as possible. thank you in advance